# Visualizing a huge graph like wikipedia

Tags: linux, data-structures, open-source, graph

I have a hugh graph structure like wikipedia. I have the adjacency list for the graph as it is very sparse. Is there a open source software to visualize the graph and zoom in and out.

Comment: Wikipedia visualized with [Gephi](http://gephi.org): http://thepoliticsofsystems.net/2011/04/11/mapping-wikipedia-going-english/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is a very well known OSS graphing tool. If you can print your graph in one of its supported formats you should be ready to go.

Answer (score 2):

[Gephi](http://gephi.org/) would be a good solution. It offers many display styles and layouts as well as using OpenGL to render the graph which makes it fast. It can also read a variety of formats and is extensible.